# No voltage after changing light switches

Tags: electrical, switch, voltage

I turned the power off and replaced a few light switches... and when I turned the breaker back on, one of the switches on a circuit is not working. There are a few other switches on the same circuit that ARE working. I used a voltage tester with the power on and it's not detecting anything. I checked the house for GFIs that are tripped, but they all seem to be OK. Any idea what is going on here? It was a simple 2-wire Legrand switch and I connected the wires to the two brass screws (nothing to green screw). thank you.

[image]

Comment: Were ALL the original switches SPST (two contacts)?

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the switch box?